# Drawing table multicolumn in Latex

Tags: multicolumn

I have a problem for drawing a table in latex. I want to have a table with 13 columns at the end. I did the biggest thing of the work. I have this following table :

[image]

But I have a problem for the first line. I want to put Historical (1850-2005) in the third column of the first line. 
Here it's my code :

```
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{test}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[b]{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{PAST1000 (850-1850)} &\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{HISTORICAL (1850-2005)} \\
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Ablation} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Accumulation} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{GrIS} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Ablation} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Accumulation} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{GrIS}\\
\hline
& SMB & ST2 & SMB & ST2 & SMB & ST2  & SMB & ST2 & SMB & ST2 & SMB & ST2\\
\hline
CESM & 0.25 & -0.044 & -0.92 & -0.042 & -0.67 & -0.043 & -6.24& 0.5 & 6.15& 0.5 & -0.09& 0.5\\
CCSM4 & -0.71 & -0.062 & -2.71 & -0.067 & -3.42 & -0.065 & -25.42& 0.91 & -8.15& 0.95 & -33.57& 0.93\\
IPSL-CM5A-LR &  & -0.025 &  & -0.024 &  & -0.024 & -0.52& 0.85 & 14.83& 1.13 & 14.31& 1.03\\
MRI-CGCM3 & 0.24 & -0.018 & -0.26 & -0.024 & -0.02 & -0.022 & -24.85& 0.78 & 13.61& 0.68 & -11.24& 0.71\\
\hline
Average Models & -1.7 & -0.037 & -1.21 & -0.04 & -2.91 & -0.039 & -14.26& 0.76 & 6.61& 0.81 & -7.65& 0.79\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I think if you change both `\multicolumn`s of the first line to `\multicolumn{6}...` you'll get what you want...

Comment: I use this site: [http://www.tablesgenerator.com/](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/) to create tables and then, export its code to LaTex. It's very simple and easy to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve the desired position of 'historical...' you have to change `\multicolumn{3}` to `\multicolumn{6}`.

Please note, that as you did not provide the documentclass, I simply chose one. Additionally, I decreased the font size, as the table was (and still is) too large to fit on the page.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\footnotesize
\caption{test}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[b]{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{PAST1000 (850-1850)} &\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{HISTORICAL (1850-2005)} \\
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Ablation} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Accumulation} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{GrIS} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Ablation} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Accumulation} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{GrIS}\\
\hline
& SMB & ST2 & SMB & ST2 & SMB & ST2  & SMB & ST2 & SMB & ST2 & SMB & ST2\\
\hline
CESM & 0.25 & -0.044 & -0.92 & -0.042 & -0.67 & -0.043 & -6.24& 0.5 & 6.15& 0.5 & -0.09& 0.5\\
CCSM4 & -0.71 & -0.062 & -2.71 & -0.067 & -3.42 & -0.065 & -25.42& 0.91 & -8.15& 0.95 & -33.57& 0.93\\
IPSL-CM5A-LR &  & -0.025 &  & -0.024 &  & -0.024 & -0.52& 0.85 & 14.83& 1.13 & 14.31& 1.03\\
MRI-CGCM3 & 0.24 & -0.018 & -0.26 & -0.024 & -0.02 & -0.022 & -24.85& 0.78 & 13.61& 0.68 & -11.24& 0.71\\
\hline
Average Models & -1.7 & -0.037 & -1.21 & -0.04 & -2.91 & -0.039 & -14.26& 0.76 & 6.61& 0.81 & -7.65& 0.79\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Although the above example fixes the problem you described, I would suggest a different layout. The following MWE does not need vertical lines, uses horizontal lines with appropriate spacing above and below from `booktabs` and aligns the numbers with respect to their decimal separators sing `S` columns from the `siunitx` package:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\caption{test}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[b]{l
                   S[table-format=-1.2]
                   S[table-format=-1.3]
                   S[table-format=-1.2]
                   S[table-format=-1.3]
                   S[table-format=-1.2]
                   S[table-format=-1.3]
                   S[table-format=-2.2]
                   S[table-format=1.2]
                   S[table-format=-2.2]
                   S[table-format=1.2]
                   S[table-format=-2.2]
                   S[table-format=-1.2]}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{PAST1000 (850-1850)} &\multicolumn{6}{c}{HISTORICAL (1850-2005)} \\
\cmidrule(r){2-7} \cmidrule(l){8-13}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Ablation} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Accumulation} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{GrIS} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Ablation} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Accumulation} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{GrIS}\\
\cmidrule(r){2-3}  \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-9} \cmidrule(lr){10-11} \cmidrule(l){12-13} 
& {SMB} & {ST2} & {SMB} & {ST2} & {SMB} & {ST2}  & {SMB} & {ST2} & {SMB} & {ST2} & {SMB} & {ST2}\\

CESM & 0.25 & -0.044 & -0.92 & -0.042 & -0.67 & -0.043 & -6.24& 0.5 & 6.15& 0.5 & -0.09& 0.5\\
CCSM4 & -0.71 & -0.062 & -2.71 & -0.067 & -3.42 & -0.065 & -25.42& 0.91 & -8.15& 0.95 & -33.57& 0.93\\
IPSL-CM5A-LR &  & -0.025 &  & -0.024 &  & -0.024 & -0.52& 0.85 & 14.83& 1.13 & 14.31& 1.03\\
MRI-CGCM3 & 0.24 & -0.018 & -0.26 & -0.024 & -0.02 & -0.022 & -24.85& 0.78 & 13.61& 0.68 & -11.24& 0.71\\
\midrule
Average Models & -1.7 & -0.037 & -1.21 & -0.04 & -2.91 & -0.039 & -14.26& 0.76 & 6.61& 0.81 & -7.65& 0.79\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]